# How many different bit strings of length 10 contain at most eight 1's?

Tags: combinatorics

How many different bit strings of length 10 contain at most eight 1's?

**My work**

$C(10,0)$+$C(10,1)$+$C(10,2)$+$C(10,3)$+$C(10,4)$+$C(10,5)$+$C(10,6)$+$C(10,7)$+$C(10,8)$

Comment: How many do **not** contain at most eight ones? How many are they at all?

Comment: That is correct, but tedious to simplify further.  If you wish to actually simplify to get a workable number you can easily evaluate the complementary event of counting how many bit strings of length 10 contain strictly more than eight 1's.

Comment: So, what I did was right

Comment: Yes, but as already mentioned, quite tedious.

Comment: This is not a probability problem.  Problems in which you are counting arrangements should be tagged combinatorics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sake of removing this from unanswered queue:

Yes, your answer is correct, albeit tedious.

A more concise way of finding and writing the answer would be to count the complementary event.  There are $\binom{10}{10}+\binom{10}{9}=1+10=11$ ways to get a string of length ten with strictly more than eight 1's.

Subtracting this from $2^{10}=1024$, the total number of length ten binary strings with no other restrictions, gives us the total number of length ten binary strings with eight or fewer 1's as:

$$2^{10}-\binom{10}{10}-\binom{10}{9}=1024-11=1013$$

I would not have wanted to try adding $\binom{10}{0}+\binom{10}{1}+\binom{10}{2}+\dots+\binom{10}{8}$ manually in a direct fashion, but using the above the arithmetic was quite easy to work with.